# Запустить функцию по клику и передать в нее объект jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, функции

Есть функция в теле документа:

```
$(function() {
$('.tab-selector').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var tab = $(this).data('tab'),
        forma = $('#fast_'+tab);
    $('#'+tab).show().siblings('div').hide();
    go_fast_order(forma);
} })
```

По клику выполняется функция `go_fast_order(forma)`, в которую пробую передать объект. Функция находится в подключаемом js, вот она:

```
function go_fast_order(el){
var forma = $(el).serialize(),
    data = 'q=checkout_fast.php&',
data = data + forma + "&action=yes";
$.ajax({
    url : "ajax.php",
    dataType : "html",
    data : data,
    type : "GET",
    success : function(msg) {
    }
});}
```

Клик происходит по элементу `<li data-tab="one" class="tab-selector">`. Но не срабатывает `serialize()`. Пробовал, так объявлять форму `var forma = el.serialize()`, безрезультатно.
Если прямо указывать нужный id формы, например `#fast_one`, работает без проблем.
Прошу подсказать, в чем моя ошибка.

Comment: "если прямо указываем нужный id" - где именно указываем? при вызове внутри `go_fast_order`, или внутри в `forma = $(el).serialize()`?

Comment: ну, короче, console.log(forma) непосредственно перед вызовом, и console.log(el) внутри функции сразу первой строчкой... смотрим, сравниваем, дальше видно будет

Comment: "Семён Семёныч !" Благодарю за ответ. И проверял же ж с помощью console.log(). Моя невнимательность, поменял атрибуты у data и жду счастья. Все равно спасибо, заставили усомниться и проверить еще раз.. А не подскажите как закрыть тему?

Answer (score 0):

`$(el).serialize()` - здесь надо просто `el.serialize()`, т.к. в функцию уже передается объект jQuery